# i Example watchdog code showing error in python

Tags: python, watchdog

i copied an example code

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

if __name__ == "__main__":
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
observer.start()
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
observer.join()
```

please help me 
i am new to python ad watchdog

i also require some more answers for the following questions:
In what form ,the output of the following code shown and where?
how do i change the directory to be monitored in the code?

and tried running it as it was by saving it in a file test.py usig the following

> python C:\folder\test.py

it returned the following erros

```
C:\Python33>python c:\folder\test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\folder\test.py", line 4, in <module>
from watchdog.observers import Observer
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\__init__.py", line 34,
in <module>
from watchdog.observers.api import BaseObserver, DEFAULT_OBSERVER_TIMEOUT
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\api.py", line 62, in <module>
from watchdog.utils.bricks import OrderedSetQueue as SetQueue
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\watchdog\utils\bricks.py", line 112, in <module>
if not sys.version < (2, 6, 0):
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < tuple()
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a bug in watchdog. It works in Python 2.6 and 2.7. `sys.version` is a string in both and comparable with a tuple. Seems like a strange idea to me.

This behavior may have changed with 3.x. If it has not been tested properly with 3.x, you should expect more trouble. It is still safest to use Python 2.7 because many libraries have not made a 3.x support.

Anyway, if you really, really want to overcome the problem, you could patch the line 112 in watchdog\utils\bricks.py:

```
ver = tuple([int(x) for x in sys.version.split()[0].split('.')])
if not ver < (2, 6, 0):
```

That is really ugly. Rather use Python 2.7.

Comment: thank you for your reply sir

i tried the code with python 2.7 

now it does not show any output

Comment: it does not show any output 

also

In what form ,the output of the following code shown and where?
 how do i change the directory to be monitored in the code?

Comment: You should check the documentation for Python `logging` module and watchdog.